# Django queryset, User model and datetime format

Tags: django, python-datetime

I want to filter my queryset as below

```
Post.objects.select_related().filter(dt_published__range=[post_start_date, now])
```

for the post_start_date, I would like to use

```
user_start_date = User.objects.filter(username=request.user).values_list('date_joined')
```

and go 7 days back from there

I can't do

```
post_start_date = user_start_date - timedelta(days=7)
```

because the result of user_start_date gives me output as this

```
[(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 19, 16, 55, 29, 27064),)]
```

any idea how can I change the output of user_start_date so I can manipulate the date ?

thanks
-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user_start_date without using `values_list`. Please try this:

```
# request.user is already a User object
user_start_date = request.user.date_joined

# Now this should work
post_start_date = user_start_date - timedelta(days=7)
```